# How to calculate sum of each pair of digits from two numbers in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have Textbox1.Lines - I want to calculate sum each digit with each digit. I think need substring method, 4+7 / 4+4 / 1+7 / and so on.

## Example

Input:

```
47
14
```

Expected Output:

```
Textbox2.Text = 

11
15
8
8
5
11
```

Comment: yes that would probably help you. What have you tried so far? It's unclear specifically what your issue is.

Comment: It's unclear where the numbers in the second sample come from. I can see most of them, but `15` makes no sense (did you mean `16`?) And if you add up all four digits, why not the possible combinations of three digits (12, 9, 15, 12)?

Comment: Still unclear on how you came up with all the numbers in your second TextBox.

Comment: each digit added with each digit, all possible combinations. if we have 47 and 14, then we will take 4 with 4 for example, but also 47 + 4. that is, it is possible to calculate the combinations of 2 digits with one digit, not just one digit with one digit.

Comment: I guess 15 was just a typo. I think he meant 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the cleanest way, but this code should do the trick:

```
    'Get all chars
    Dim lstAllChars As List(Of Char) = TextBox1.Text.ToList
    'Filter numeric chars
    lstAllChars = lstAllChars.Where(Function(x) x >= "0"c And x <= "9"c).ToList

    Dim lstSum As New List(Of Integer)
    'Loop each char
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstAllChars.Count - 1
        Dim iFirstInt = CType(lstAllChars(i).ToString, Integer)
        'Add the second char
        For y As Integer = i + 1 To lstAllChars.Count - 1
            Dim iSecondInt = CType(lstAllChars(y).ToString, Integer)
            lstSum.Add(iFirstInt + iSecondInt)
        Next
    Next

    'Edit the textbox
    TextBox1.Clear()

    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
    For Each sum In lstSum
        sb.AppendLine(sum.ToString)
    Next

    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 steps in this answer:

1. Split the input in "lines"
2. Calculate the sum of the numbers on one line
3. Show the results

So here's how we'll achieve this:

```
    Dim originalString As String = "47" & vbNewLine & "14" & vbNewLine & "75"   'example string, you will use your textbox instead
    Dim results As String = ""

    Dim lines As String() = originalString.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))

    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim lineSum As Integer = 0

        For Each numberChar As Char In line
            If Asc(numberChar) >= 48 AndAlso Asc(numberChar) < 58 Then  'making sure this is a number and nothing else
                lineSum += Asc(numberChar) - 48 'using the ascii chart to determine the value tu add
            End If
        Next

        If results <> "" Then results &= vbNewLine
        results &= lineSum.ToString
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(results)
    'here you could put the 'results' string in the textbox you use for showing outputs
```

Next time let us know what you tried and how it failed, this community likes to help people who shows this kind of information. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Since they're strings to begin with you can use.
Left(str,n)  n is the number of left characters you want.
Right(str,n) n is the number of Right characters you want.
Mid(str,n,nn) Mid is like substring where n is the starting char, and nn is the number from start you want from the str.

```
Dim line1 = "47"

Dim d1 As String = Left(line1,1)   'this is 4

Dim d2 As String = Right(line1,1)  'this is 7
```

now the math

```
Dim a1 As Integer = Int(d1) + Int(d2)
```

or

```
Dim a1 As Integer = CInt(d1) + CInt(d2)
```

I think they'll both work.